# How to get ACTION_POINTER_DOWN motion event if the pointer is on another view?

Tags: android, touch-event

I have multiple views one is big and others are small views. Small views are on top of the big view and their positions can change with the dragging so they have their own touch events. Also bigger view can be pinch zoomed, however I can't pinch zoom the bigger view if the second finger is on a small view, because then that small view gets the ACTION_DOWN motion event and bigger view never gets the ACTION_POINTER_DOWN. I can't return false in the small views because they are called with ACTION_DOWN and I can't be sure if user is dragging the small view or just pinch zooming the bigger view.

Comment: Why not let the big view manage all the interaction (i.e., drag small views, zoom, etc.)?

Comment: Because small views are part of a library( my own  lib) project and included in multiple projects.